# Java Out-of-Memory Error in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My problem is fairly simple: the JVM is running out of memory when I run `RandomForest.trainRegressor` in `pyspark`. I'm using about 3GB of training data, 77 features, and with `numTrees` set to 15. If I set `numTrees` to 15 or more, the training fails with an out-of-memory error (like below):

```
error info:
model = RandomForest.trainRegressor(trainingData, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},numTrees=15, featureSubsetStrategy="sqrt",impurity='variance', maxDepth=20, maxBins=14) #variance
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/tree.py", line 412, in trainRegressor
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/tree.py", line 270, in _train
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 130, in callMLlibFunc
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 123, in callJavaFunc
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o81.trainRandomForestModel.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1785)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1188)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2032)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:703)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:702)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:702)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree$.findBestSplits(DecisionTree.scala:625)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest.run(RandomForest.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest$.trainRegressor(RandomForest.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.PythonMLLibAPI.trainRandomForestModel(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:744)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
```

I'm using `spark` 1.5 and my parameters are:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=x.x.x.x \
    --jars /home/retail/packages/spark_cassandra_tool-1.0.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/hive/lib/HiveAuthHook.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/hbase/hbase-common.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/hbase/hbase-client.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/hbase/hbase-server.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/lib/spark-examples.jar \
    --num-executors 30 --executor-cores 4 \
    --executor-memory 20000M --driver-memory 200g \
    --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=5000 \
    --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=2000m \
    --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer=40m \
    --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=\"-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=5g\" \
    --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=10g \
    --conf spark.port.maxRetries=100
```

1. In my opinion, the trees should be trained in series, so why does the number of them create a higher memory load?
2. If I want to train 300 trees successfully, how should I set the `spark` parameters to use the `RandomForest.trainRegressor` function properly?

Comment: Trees need to be aggregated, hence more could lead to OOM.

Comment: You cluster is not small. What is the depth of your model?

Comment: The parameter maxDepth is set to 20,I reduce training set to 300M,and after run a long time,it still failed.

Comment: And also I changed java heap's parameter to :-Xms10000m -Xmx10000m

Comment: Tree num is set to 300

Comment: Just another thought: what is the spec of your cluster (because you config values look pretty large)? Set the cluster to use more memory than it can have could also lead to issues like this.